# Forming URI for resource with composed primary key

Tags: rest, uri

I am working with RESTful webservices and I have a special requirement, I need to pull up a record from the DB but the record has a composed Primary Key. How would you suggest forming the URI in a way that it contemplates that case?

In my perspective, the typical cases are:

```
//brings the product whose PK is 1
http://mywebsite.com/products/1

//brings all the products
http://mywebsite.com/products
```

Comment: this question can be improved. please change "PK" to be full words, and also format your url use cases so that way they are readible (maybe as a list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In REST, URIs identify resources. As you write, the canonical way to identify a resource is

```
/products/{id}
```

Since you need composed primary keys, I basically see two options.

### Use two path segments

You could use a patter like this:

```
/products/{key1}/{key2}
```

Together `key1` and `key2` would identify the product.

The problem with this approach is that `key1` can be interpreted to be "above" `key2`. There *could* be resources like

```
/products/foo/bar
```

and

```
/products/foo/baz
```

where `key1` is `foo` in both cases but `key2` is different. If your key components can be interpreted like this, I would recommend to use this approach.

### Use query parameters

If you want to avoid an order of the key parts, you can use query parameters.

```
/products?key1=foo&key2=bar
```

In this approach, `key1` and `key2` have no special order, none is "above" the other.

The problem with this approach is that an URL like this is normally interpreted as a filtered collection: return all products where `key1=foo` and `key2=bar`. But you don't ask for a (filtered) collection but single product.

### Summary

I recommend to use the first approach if your key components are not required to be completely equal.